# How to use all() and any() function in pandas with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need one help regarding: How to use `all` and `any` function in Pandas with multiple columns. Below is my data frame:

```
               ResolutionCodeMapID  CauseCodeMapID  TicketTypeMapID  multiple
ApplicationID                                                                
129272                          61              12               48      True
```

[image]

Here I want `True` in multiple columns, if all column values are greater than 60.
If all col values are greater than 30 also, I need as `True`.
If any one column value is less than 10, then it should be `False`.

I'v tried the code below, but it's not giving the expected answer:

```
df["multiple"] = (df[cols]>=50).all(axis="columns")
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution generate `True` if all values are greater or equal like `10` with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
cols = ['CauseCodeMapID','CauseCodeMapID','TicketTypeMapID']

df["multiple"] = df["multiple"] = (df[cols]>=10).all(axis=1)
print (df)
        ResolutionCodeMapID  CauseCodeMapID  TicketTypeMapID  multiple
129272                   61              12               48      True
129272                   61              12                8     False
```

Or:

```
df["multiple"] = np.where((df[cols]<10).any(axis=1), False, True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @jezrael..  :)  let me try it

Comment: @smilepet - Can you add some numbers which failed to question?

Comment: it's working now. i just used >,< to validate the condition. But how can we use and / or operation in single code. Because in above examples we just used only one condition. if possible can you share how can test and / or condition in single code. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @smilepet - do you think `(df[cols]<10).any(axis=1) | (df['col'] > 5)` ?

Comment: yes, it's exactly..  this is the one want. i tried like this (df[cols]>40 and df[cols]<50).all(axis=1).. that's my mistake. Thanks a lot again :) @jezrael